# How to make JPA interpret List<Element> (size only 0 or 1) as single Element

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate-mapping

```
class Entity {
    private InnnerEntity innerEntity;
}
```

I had above structure in JPA previously, but now I have to change it to collection like:

```
class Entity {
    private List<InnnerEntity> innerEntity;
}
```

And this list will contain only 1 or 0 elements. So I need to make JPA work with that structure exactly as it was before. I mean to still have mapping one to one or in other case have it as an embedded entity.
Is that even possible ?

Comment: why not keeping is as a single element and use null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to limit the size of a @OneToMany collection with Hibernate or JPA Annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328187/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-size-of-a-onetomany-collection-with-hibernate-or-jp)

Comment: @Karim we have tricky case where we use 3rd party library and it needs to have it as a collection. And on another end we have production data which operates through these JPA entities.

Comment: @mentallurg no, unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: @YaroslavKovbas: But that is exactly what yre you trying to do: Yoiu want to limit the size of relation to max. 1 element. That post explains why you cannot do that.

Comment: Well, this is not possible with JPA, but what you can do is set a Validation trigger in the database, what kind of database you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bean validation to limit the size of the collection to 1 but you will have to use OneToMany because OneToOne doesn't work on collections:

```
class Entity {

    @Size(1)
    @OneToMany
    private List<InnnerEntity> innerEntity;

}
```