# Limit nested collection size in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have an entity called Client:

```
@Entity
public class Client extends User {

    

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Activity> activities = new HashSet<>();
```

When I retrieve a Client object, also my nested collection are filled. Which is the best way to limit the size of these collection? I should avoid to retrieve them and manually execute a query for each collection? Which should be the best approach considering performance?

Comment: Off-topic, just a friendly recommendation, please use English comments in your code, as well :) (it will be useful for future developers).

Comment: It is a project I'm developing for studying Spring Boot :)

Comment: Just to clarify - do you mean how to limit the size of the collection that is *saved* or *retrieved*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to limit the size of a @OneToMany collection with Hibernate or JPA Annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328187/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-size-of-a-onetomany-collection-with-hibernate-or-jp)